# Error Logic Gates

Tags: transistors, resistor-transistor-logic

[image]
[image]

I connect this 5 transistor and,or,nor,nand,inverter respectively into to switches to operate.. I also add Exor and Exnor.. the Exor I made consists of 4 Nand gates based on the nand diagram stated on the diagram... the exnor was also made out of the 4 nand gate plus an inverter... upon checking one by one of the 7 logic gate, it functions well.. but when connected into to switches, some functions well, some gates do not.. what is this problem and how to fix it??

Answer (score 1):

The gates you show can be used only under very limnited circumstances. Except for the NOR and the inverter (which lacks a base resistor!), they are based on emitter followers. A property of an emitter follower is that *the output is ~ 0.6V lower than the input*. This is OK for one or two stages in series, but after a few more the logic signal is lost (will be 0). An inverter (or NOR) every few gates will solve this, but that is a very error-prone way of designing lgic.

BTW

- Your emitter-folower base gates do NOT need base resistors.
- The output '1' level should be higher than 1.8V, I would expect ~ 5V when unloaded
- with a 4k7 pull-up and a 10k base resistor (for NOR and inverter) your fan-out (the number of inputs that connect to an output) will be very low.

Comment: How about replacing the 5V source into 9V.. My problem is that some gates dont functions weel. I mean they supposed to have a 1 input which works when they are tested alone. but when these 7 logic gates are connected and has only 2 switches as their common switch, some dont have an input already which is supposedly has when referring to the truth table.. whats the main problem?

Comment: The main problem is that the design is bad. 9V will hide the poblems a litte, which is maybe worse. I'd say: take you NOR gate, replace 4k7 with 470 Ohm, and forget all other gates (you can leave out 1 transistor to make it a NOT gate). And remember to connect no more than 10 inputs to each output.

Comment: So you want me to replace the 4.7kohm on the NOR gate with a 470 ohms.. and let the 4.7kohm resitor be on the rest of the gates? in that case, am I assured that when the 7 gates (and,or,nor,nand,inverter,exor,exnor) will now function well without any problem? My goal is to combine the 7 gates and leave only 2 switches for all..

Comment: Can you give me a sample of these 7 logic gate combination having only 2 switches to operate these gates? the resistor value used, the transistor used, etc .. etc ..I am really having trouble to make this combination works fine.

Comment: No, I want you to replace that resistor and design only with that NOR gate (and its reduced for, the NOT gate). You can make any function you want from only NOR gates.

Comment: really? sorry. I'm just a beginner.. so you want me to have only NOR gate on my breadboard and by doing that I can have the 7 logic gates? how I'll doing that? Can you please guide me..

Comment: NOR gate*s*, multiple. Google the basic equivalence of logic gates. Either that, or learn more electronics before deisgning your own gates at the transistor level.